# Is this shortened sentence grammatical?

Tags: ellipsis, paraphrasing

Here is a sentence from a [news article](http://www.taipeitimes.com/News/lang/archives/2015/12/23/2003635412) that was translated from Chinese and published in an English-language newspaper in Taiwan:

> The three-section batons are 65 centimeters long, but when retracted they are only 25 centimeters in length.

I think this sentence is a bit too wordy, so I wonder if I can shorten it into this without compromising grammar or the meaning:

> The three-section batons are 65 centimeters long, but only 25 cm when retracted.

The shortened version sounds okay to me, but since grammar is not one of my strong points, any opinion is appreciated.

Comment: Both the original sentence and your revision are grammatically standard. Whether one is "wordy" or not is a question of style and can lead to comprehensive discussion. There are many other ways to shorten and arrange the expression of the original idea. Some variations will tend to send various connotations, including emphasizing different information components.

Comment: I agree with @JimReynolds' caveats; but in this case your sentence is superior to the original, especially in eliminating the false contrast between  *long* and *in length*.

Comment: Yes, I found it in the Taipei Times. I am working on my Chinese-English translation. Thank both of you for your answers. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It sounds perfectly all right. You could also convert it to :

> The three-section batons, 65 centimeters long, can be retracted down to 25 centimeters.

But that is just a suggestion. Honestly, your sentence should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your revision is grammatical, and keeps the original's meaning.

We can further reduce it:

> The three-section batons are 65 centimeters long, but retract to only 25 centimeters.

Whether we could use *cm* would probably be dictated by the newspaper's style guidelines. I think their copy editors would want it consistent, not *centimeters* in the first clause and *cm* in the second.